# How to reset the offset in REST proxy for reconsuming Kafka messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I consumed some messages from the Kafka queue, and now I want to consume them again (just fetch all data from the beginning). How can I reset the offset in Scala or using [Kafka Rest Proxy](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/clients/consumer.html)? I am currently using `"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"`:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.kafka.v1+json" \
      --data '{"format": "json", "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}' \
      XXX.XX.XXX.XXX:9092/consumers/test
```

Please notice that I am not interested in the solution

Comment: What client library are you using for consuming the messages? Can you paste in the code? Also -  _not interested in the solution_ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last param in the URL is **group Id**. Kafka stores committed offset per group Id. So, changing group Id should be enough (.../consumers/newGroupId).